# Como implementar o ReactJS em uma aplicação Electron?

Tags: electron, react

Olá, bom, estou começando um aplicativo no Electron, mas digamos que fiz em duas partes, uma parte, a do Electron, a configuração está ok, só que a outra parte fiz em outros arquivos usando o ReactJS, que está relativamente pronta, falta uns ajustes. Minha dúvida é o seguinte, como faço para que essa parte que fiz no ReactJS eu implemente no Electron?

Não vou conseguir mostrar os códigos pois seria complicado, mas para tentar facilitar vou colocar uns prints das pastas.

[image: Esta é a pasta onde o Electron está, sendo que o arquivo principal é o main.js que é onde configuro o Electron, os htlms digo que seriam irrelevantes para tal dúvida. E o package.json colocarei em outro print.]

[image: Eu cheguei a instalar o react mas como não sei o fazer então não fui adiante.]

[image: Aí é o "puclic" do React, que diria que é irrelevante também para tal problema]

[image: E aqui é onde a parte do React funciona. No App.js mas especificadamente no render, seria outra browserWindow do Electron. O index.js seria o "main", estarei colocando um print. E o registerServiceWorking.js vou dizer que não sei muito bem para que serve.]

[image: E este como disse, é o index, onde ele importa as coisas(não sei o termo correto para este caso).]

**Primeira imagem.** Esta é a pasta onde o Electron está, sendo que o arquivo principal é o main.js que é onde configuro o Electron, os htlms digo que seriam irrelevantes para tal dúvida. E o package.json colocarei em outro print.

**Segunda imagem.** Eu cheguei a instalar o react mas como não sei o fazer então não fui adiante.

**Terceira imagem.** Aí é o "puclic" do React, que diria que é irrelevante também para tal problema.

**Quarta imagem.** E aqui é onde a parte do React funciona. No App.js mas especificadamente no render, seria outra browserWindow do Electron. O index.js seria o "main", estarei colocando um print. E o registerServiceWorking.js vou dizer que não sei muito bem para que serve.

**Quinta imagem.** E este como disse, é o index, onde ele importa as coisas(não sei o termo correto para este caso).

E para deixar claro, sou novato em tais assuntos e no StackOverflow, desculpem se a formatação ficou ruim. E caso alguém queira que eu esclareça algo que não deixei claro, é só falar que estarei esclarecendo. E peço desculpas caso não não tenham entendido qualquer outra coisa. Espero que tenha dado para entender. Obrigado desde já.